# onPageFinished gets called after onReceivedError in WebViewClient

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

I have a webview with WebViewClient. I want to display some alert if any error occurs.So I have overriden OnPageFinished & OnRecivedError.

My problem is tat OnPageFinshed is getting called after OnReceivedError.
Is this a sequence of callbacks tat android perform or we can avoid this,means not to call  OnPageFinshedafter OnReceivedError.

any help is most welcome

Answer (score 3):

If you receive the error when the page loading is finished.It is really normal that after onErrorReceived onPageFinished will be called because you are getting the error when you are finished the page request and that's why it is getting called normally.